# how to transfer serialized data from SQL Database to cosmos Db

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I am facing problem while transferring SQL table data to Cosmos DB.
My SQL table contains one column which contain serialized data like

`'[{"Id":"1","Name":"AA","Address":"HQ - Main Line"}]'`.

while using '`Document Db Data migration tool`' it creates all documents properly but property of document which holds serialized data
which contains value

```
"info": "[{\"Id\":\"1\",\"Name\":\"AA\",\"Address\":\"HQ - Main Line\"}]"
```

data migration tool adds extra backslash for `"` but i want same as SQL table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using migration tool to import data so that you can't use [PreTrigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/programming#database-pre-triggers) to change the format of created documents.[PreTrigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/programming#database-pre-triggers) need to be invoked by code or rest api.

I suggest you using Azure Function Cosmos DB Trigger. Please refer to my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.Azure.Documents;
using Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

namespace ProcessJson
{
    public class Class1
    {
        [FunctionName("DocumentUpdates")]
        public static void Run(
        [CosmosDBTrigger(databaseName:"db",collectionName: "item", ConnectionStringSetting = "CosmosDBConnection",LeaseCollectionName = "leases",
            CreateLeaseCollectionIfNotExists = true)]
        IReadOnlyList<Document> documents,
        TraceWriter log)
        {
            log.Verbose("Start.........");
            String endpointUrl = "https://***.documents.azure.com:443/";
            String authorizationKey = "***";
            String databaseId = "db";
            String collectionId = "import";

            DocumentClient client = new DocumentClient(new Uri(endpointUrl), authorizationKey);

            for (int i = 0; i < documents.Count; i++)
            {
                Document doc = documents[i];
                String info = doc.GetPropertyValue<String>("info");
                JArray o = JArray.Parse(info);

                doc.SetPropertyValue("info", o);

                client.ReplaceDocumentAsync(UriFactory.CreateDocumentUri(databaseId, collectionId, doc.Id), doc);

                log.Verbose("Update document Id " + doc.Id);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Hope it helps you.